# Trouble getting an Authentication Token using Axios for React

Tags: authentication, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to grab an authentication token using axios in a react app.

Here is the error I'm getting is:
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400"

Here is my code.

```
 var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      token: ''
    }
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;

    axios.post('https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token', {
      grant_type: 'password',
      username: 'jpdesigning',
      password: 'Upahem2_88'
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log('Success!')
      _this.setState({
        token: response.data
      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
   },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
           {this.state.token}
      </div>
     );
  }
})

export default App;
```

Comment: Make sure your server support cors request and print response.data to check what returned from server.

Comment: I tried to return response.data but i'm not getting getting any response becasue its catching the error instead. Its saying a 400 Bad request. What is bad about it though?

Comment: It could be `cors` related issue. Try sending `cors` request using `axios`.

Comment: xhr.js:175 OPTIONS https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:175xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
localhost/:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.mmitnetwork.com/Token.Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400
App.js:31 Error: Network Error(…)

Answer (score 0):

Your server needs to allow cross-origin (CORS) clients to access your headers by setting the following header on your server's response and telling it which headers they are (here you are allowing two headers: Authorization & Permissions - i.e. including custom headers)

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization, Permissions
```

Headers that are accessible by default:

```
Cache-Control
Content-Language
Content-Type
Expires
Last-Modified
Pragma
```

Read here [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

**example from php server for full CORS access**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size,
X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

Comment: You should also make your server respond to OPTIONS requests even without authorization. It seems like this is the error 400 you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `withCredentials: true,` header , this will send the cookie along with this request